# Make sure c# winforms application calls specific function before terminating

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

Is there a way to call a function in a C# Windows forms application before the application exits, independent of the event that closed the application (i.e. closing by pressing 'X', terminating through taskmanager, etc.)

Sorry I didn't see that the question was already answered but the formulation of the question didn't let me find what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`FormClosing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
}

void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //Do your stuff before form is closed
}
```

Comment: will OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) also work?

Comment: @Steffen....`OnFormClosing` Raises the `FormClosing` event.